# Best way to synchronise threads and measure performance at sub-microsecond frequency

Tags: c, multithreading, timing

I'm working on a standard x86 six core SMP machine, 3.6GHz clock speed, plain C code.

I have a threaded producer/consumer scheme in which my "producer" thread is reading from file at roughly 1,000,000 lines/second, and handing the data it reads off to either two or four "consumer" threads which do a bit of work on it and then stick it into a database. While they are consuming it is busy reading the next line.

So both producer and consumers have to have some means of synchronisation which works at sub-microsecond frequency, for which I use a "busy spin wait" loop, because all the normal synchronisation mechanisms I can find are just too slow.   In pseudo code terms:

Producer thread

```
While(something in file)
{
   read a line
   populate 1/2 of data double buffer
   wait for consumers to idle
   set some key data
   set memory fence
   swap buffers
}
```

And the consumer threads likewise

```
while(not told to die)
{
   wait for key data change event
   consume data
}
```

At both sides the "wait" loop is coded:

```
while(waiting)
{
   _mm_pause();      /* Intel say this is a good hint to processor that this is a spin wait */

    if(#iterations > 1000) yield_thread();  /* Sleep(0) on Windows, pthread_yield() on Linux */
}
```

This all works, and I get some quite nice speed-ups compared to the equivalent serial code, but my profiler (Intel's VTune Amplifier) shows that I am spending a horrendous amount of time in my busy wait loops, and the ratio of "spin" to "useful work done" is depressingly high.  Given the way the profiler concentrates its feedback on the busiest sections this also means that the lines of code doing useful work tend not to be reported, since (relatively speaking) their %age of total cpu is down at the noise level ... or at least that is what the profiler is saying.   They must be doing *something* otherwise I wouldn't see any speed up!

I can and do time things, but it is hard to distinguish between delays imposed by disk latency in the producer thread, and delays spent while the threads synchronise.

So is there a better way to measure what is actually going on?  By which I mean just how much time are these threads *really* spending waiting for one another?  Measuring time accurately is really hard at sub-microsecond resolution, the profiler doesn't seem to give me much help, and I am struggling to optimise the scheme.

Or maybe my spin wait scheme is rubbish, but I can't seem to find a better solution for sub-microsecond synchronisation.

Any hints would be really welcome :-)

Comment: did you try parallelization using openmp? task distribution will be done for you as well as synchro, and it is usually a good place to start with.

Comment: The solution is to give the consumers bigger chunks to work on, so that you don't need sub-microsecond synchronization.

Comment: When there's nothing in the queue the consumer must wait for something to arrive (and if/when the queue is full the producer must wait for something to be removed). This waiting is best done with kernel/scheduler support (in a "don't give me any CPU time until..." way) to avoid busy waiting (especially when you're waiting for a task that isn't running on any CPU because the kernel decided to give a completely unrelated task some CPU time).

Comment: OznOg: Yes I did try OpenMP.   My thread "manager" is my own version of OpenMP: a pool of threads which sleep until woken for use, then return to a sleep wait state.   I don't see how OpenMP would help the producer/consumer load balancing problem at this sort of frequency though.

user3386109: "More work" is the lightbulb that went off in my head last night as well (possibly telepathy at work?).  I think I can see how to implement this and I'll give it a try.

Brendan: I tried WaitForSingleObject(). It worked but was too slow, however with a larger chunk size it might be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than fast locks is not locking at all. Try switching to a [lock-free queue](https://www.liblfds.org/). Producers and consumers wouldn't need to wait at all.

> Lock-free data structures are process, thread and interrupt safe (i.e. the same data structure instance can be safely used concurrently and simultaneously across cores, processes, threads and both inside and outside of interrupt handlers), never sleep (and so are safe for kernel use when sleeping is not permitted), operate without context switches, cannot fail (no need to handle error cases, as there are none), perform and scale literally orders of magnitude better than locking data structures, and liblfds itself (as of release 7.0.0) is implemented such that it performs no allocations (and so works with NUMA, stack, heap and shared memory) and compiles not just on a freestanding C89 implementation, but on a bare C89 implementation.

Comment: I never knew about that, thank you.   I will have to read up about it because if it works for me it could be amazing.

Comment: I've just read your page "Memory barriers part 1" https://www.liblfds.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Article:Memory_Barriers_(part_1) and I can only say "thank you".

It explains behaviour I have observed - rarely but occasionally - that a store fence does not guarantee a write to main memory.   It also explains why a load fence trying to get that value appeared to make no difference.    I will definitely use your "perform an atomic write" trick to make the fence work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who commented above, the suggestion of making the quantum of work bigger was the key.   I have now implemented a queue (1000 entry long rotating buffer) for my consumer threads, so the producer only has to wait if that queue is full, rather than waiting for its half of the double buffer in my previous scheme. So its synchronisation time is now sub-millisecond instead of sub-microsecond - well that's a surmise, but it's definitely 1000x longer than before!

If the producer hits "queue full" I can now yield its thread immediately, instead of spin waiting, safe in the knowledge that any time slice it loses will be used gainfully by the consumer threads.   This does indeed show up as a small amount of sleep/spin time in the profiler. The consumer threads benefit too since they have a more even workload.

Net outcome is a 10% reduction in the overall time to read a file, and given that only part of the file is able to be processed in a threaded manner that suggests that the threaded part of the process is around 15% or more faster.